# Why is this migration irreversible? (change_table, rename, text)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I have what I think is a pretty simple migration. For some reason I get an `IrreversibleMigration` error when I try to `db:rollback` or `db:migrate:redo`.

The migration runs smoothly, but I'd rather keep it reversible. I can't figure out why it's not as written. Any ideas?

Here's the migration:

```
class AddWhyHypAndWhyHypeToStatements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :statements do |t|
      t.rename :description, :why_hypocritical
      t.text   :why_hypothetical
    end
  end
end
```

If it matters, "description" column is a text column. I'm using Rails 3.1/Ruby 1.9.2/PostgreSQL. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know if it is the `t.rename` or `t.text` that is causing the exception?

Comment: I do not know. I tried my rollback with `--trace`, but the output does not refer to any contents of the migration itself.

Comment: Try breaking the migration into two pieces and see which one raises the exception on rollback.

Comment: not sure of what i say, but i think you need to implement a `down` method on your migration in order to be able to rollback it

Comment: @m_x, you're right, you can implement `up` and `down` methods yourself to be able to run and revert the migration, but recently Rails introduced new method `change` for writing migrations that can be reversed automatically. See [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method) for more information.

Comment: @KL-7 hey nice, did not know that, it's clearly an improvement :D

Comment: it's reversible for me on Rails 6.1.4, so it's probably outdated

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like Rails has troubles reverting `change_table` method. Try doing it that way instead:

```
class AddWhyHypAndWhyHypeToStatements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :statements, :description, :why_hypocritical
    add_column :statements, :why_hypothetical, :text
  end
end
```

You can see the list of commands that can be inverted in the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Migration/CommandRecorder) or in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method).

Comment: Thanks, this seems right. I read the guide and docs before and thought that since my `change_table` included only a `rename` and `add_column` it would be auto-reversible by Rails. But reading the guide a little closer, I realize that's an assumption on my part and not necessarily a correct one (i.e., these commands are only reversible in their long-form, not in a `change_table` nest). I made this change, and it works. Thanks again.